# DataTables search highlight with no tr remove

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am trying to change the default behavior of DataTables search with no luck.

I am using the plugin mark.js with the [datatables.mark.js plugin](https://datatables.net/blog/2017-01-19) - [Github](https://github.com/julmot/datatables.mark.js/) (I am currently using DataTables 1.10.12).

I would like just to highlight the row with result and not to *remove* all the rows that are not matching.

I noticed that inside the function **_fnDraw** it gets the array that contains the matches.

So I tried to change that part like this:

```
function _fnDraw( oSettings )
{
    /* I just changed the following lines */
    // var aiDisplay = oSettings.aiDisplay;
    var aiDisplay = oSettings.aiDisplayMaster;
```

I also noticed that the fnDisplayEnd function is used to set a limit to the rows that need to be printed.

```
"fnDisplayEnd": function ()
    {
        var
            /* I just changed the following lines */
            //records  = this.aiDisplay.length,
            records  = this.aiDisplayMaster.length,
```

But doing like this the code brokes in another point:

```
_api_register( 'rows().nodes()', function () {
    return this.iterator( 'row', function ( settings, row ) {
        return settings.aoData[ row ].nTr || undefined;
    }, 1 );
} );
```

With the following error:
*Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nTr' of undefined*

Where *row* contains the matches got from the search

I am missing something but I don't know where.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it wrapping these to lines of code inside the **_fnDraw**

```
body.children().detach();
body.append( $(anRows) );
```

Resulting in:

```
 if(oSettings.aiDisplay.length == oSettings.aiDisplayMaster.length){
    body.children().detach();
    body.append( $(anRows) );
}
```

Since *oSettings.aiDisplay* contains the array of rows matched with the search and *oSettings.aiDisplayMaster* contains the entire table rows.

**UPDATE**

To achieve that I also hide the default search:

```
dataTables_filter {
    display:none;
}
```

and let mark.js let the dirty stuff, creating a new input field:

HTML:

```
<input id="markJsSearch" type="search" placeholder="New Custom Search">
```

JS:

```
  $input.on("input", function() {
    var searchVal = this.value;
    $content.unmark({
      done: function() {
        $content.mark(searchVal, {
          separateWordSearch: true,
          done: function() {
            $results = $content.find("mark");
            currentIndex = 0;
            jumpTo();
          }
        });
      }
    });
  });
```

ref: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/julmot/973gdh8g/)

Then I have modified *markjs* plugin (mark.js v8.11.1 - not min) in order to add a CSS class to the tr, in order to highlight it:

Line 727: [inside *key: 'wrapRangeInTextNode'*]

```
jQuery(node).parents('tr').addClass('highlight');
```

Line 991 [inside *key: 'unmark'*]

```
jQuery(node).parents('tr').removeClass('highlight');
```

and I have added the following CSS:

```
table tbody tr.highlight td {
    background: #4e98fe;
    color: #fff;
}
```

and hiding the mark.js default styling:

```
mark {
    background: transparent;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 0;
}
```

In addition I needed to add multiple select to *filter* rows, basing on the value of a certain column and I found out this awesome plugin, which worked like a charm: [Yet Another DataTables Column Filter](http://yadcf-showcase.appspot.com/DOM_source_chosen.html) Thanks!

To make it work with the mark.js trick, which basically doesn't redraw the table I add a global variable called *multiSearch* which let the table redraw if the multiple select is fired.

I created:

```
var multiSearch = true;
```

I changed DataTables plugin like this:

```
if((oSettings.aiDisplay.length == oSettings.aiDisplayMaster.length && !multiSearch)){
    body.children().detach();
    body.append( $(anRows) );
} else if(multiSearch) {
    body.children().detach();
    body.append( $(anRows) );
}
```

And add this:

```
 $('body').on('click focus','#markJsSearch',function(){
        multiSearch = false;
    }).on('blur','#markJsSearch',function(){
        multiSearch = true;
    });
```

Hope everything was clear and that can help someone!